# Definition of linguistic variable.

Tags: logic, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

A linguistic variable is defined as a quintuple $(X,T(X),U,G,M)$
where:
$$
X\text{ is the name of the variable.}
$$
$$
T(X)\text{ is the collection of linguistic values of $X$.}
$$
$$
U \text{ is a universe of discourse.}
$$
$$
G\text{ is a syntactic rule which generates the terms in $T(X)$.}
$$
$$
M \text{ is a semantic rule which associates with each linguistic value X its meaning.}
$$

Let us take $X=$ Age, and $T(X)=\{$ young, very young, old, very old, middle-aged, $\ldots\}$. What could we have as $U,G,M$? I think I do not really understand the definition of linguistic variable, so I cannot imagine a possible choice for $U,G,M$.

Comment: Maybe the reference to the paper/book may help ...

Comment: You can see LA Zadeh, [The Concept of a Linguistic Variable](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~zadeh/papers/The%20Concept%20of%20a%20Linguistic%20Variable%20and%20its%20Applications%20to%20Approximate%20Reasoning%20I-1975.pdf) (1975).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have taken the definition and the example from the first article, but I still do not know how to complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Linguistic variables and truth-values in fuzzy logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=wu0dMiIHwJkC&pg=PA291) :

> A *linguistic variable* $\mathcal X$ is a nonfuzzy variable which ranges over a collection $T (\mathcal X)$ of structured fuzzy variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ with each fuzzy variable in $T (\mathcal X)$ carrying a linguistic label $X_i$, which characterizes the fuzzy restriction which is associated with $X_i$.
>
> As an illustration, $Age$ is a linguistic variable if its values are assumed to be the fuzzy variables labeled *young, not young, very young,...* rather than the numbers $0,1,2, \ldots$ [...] Thus, if the base variable for $Age$ (i.e. numerical age) is assumed to range over the universe $U= \{ 0, 1, \ldots, 100 \}$, then the linguistic values of $Age$ may be interpreted as the labels of fuzzy subsets of $U$.
>
> More generally, a linguistic variable is characterized by a quintuple $( \mathcal X, T(\mathcal X), U, G, M )$ where $\mathcal X$ is the name of the variable, e.g. $Age$; $T(\mathcal X)$ is the *term-set* of $\mathcal X$, that is, the collection of its linguistic values, e.g. $T(\mathcal X) = \{$ *young, not young, very young*, $\ldots \}$; $U$ is a *universe* of discourse, e.g., in the case of $Age$, the set $\{ 0, 1, \ldots, 100 \}$; $G$ is a syntactic rule which generates the terms in $T(\mathcal X)$; and $M$ is a semantic rule which associates with each term $X_i$ in $T(\mathcal X)$ its *meaning* $M(X_i)$, where $M(X_i)$ is a fuzzy subset of $U$ which serves as a fuzzy restriction on the values of the fuzzy fariable $X_i$.